# Swift how to pass closure from one function to another?

Tags: swift, closures

Say that I have 2 functions:

```
functionA(@escaping closureA: ((Double) -> ())) {
    // Some Code for function A
}

functionB(@escaping closureB: ((Double) -> ())) {
    // Some Code for function B
}
```

If I want to call functionB from function A, how do I pass function A's closure parameter as argument to functionB's parameter?

Something that looks like this:

```
func A(@escaping closureA: ((Double) -> ())) {
    // Some Code for function A
    B(<trying to pass closureA>)

}

func B(@escaping closureB: ((Double) -> ())) {
    // Some Code for function B
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the in parameter to the closure to start with and then when calling the closure sent to functionB you need to supply a value as argument

```
func functionA(closureA: (@escaping (Double) -> ())) {
    functionB(closureB: closureA)
}

func functionB( closureB: (@escaping (Double) -> ())) {
    closureB(3.2)
}
```

Example

```
functionA(closureA: {print($0 * 2.0)})
```

> 6.4

Answer (score 0):

Try this example below.

```
func functionA(closure:(()->Void), completionHandler: @escaping (Double) -> Void) {
    closure()
    completionHandler(1.0)
}

func  functionB(completionHandler: @escaping (Double) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(2.0)
}

func nestedClosure() {
    functionA(closure: {
        functionB { (value) in
            print("\(value)")
        }
    }, completionHandler: { (value) in
        print("\(value)")
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solution is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Welcome bro. Check your appropriate answer.